# Как в Node.js использовать библиотеку С++?

Tags: c++, node.js, lib

Есть (динамическая) библиотека C++ с таким содержимым:

```
// main.cpp

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

extern "C"
{
    // A function adding two integers and returning the result
    int SampleAddInt(int i1, int i2)
    {
        return i1 + i2;
    }

    std::vector<int> Addition(int v)
    {
        std::vector<int> x = {1, 2, 3};
        return x;
    }
}
```

Нужно подключить и использовать функции из нее в модуле **Node.js**.

```
var ref = require('ref');
var ffi = require('ffi');

var testlib = ffi.Library('/home/anton/Documents/CodeBlocks_projects/testlib/bin/Release/liblibtestlib.so', {
    'SampleAddInt': [ 'int', [ 'int', 'int' ] ],
    'Addition': [ ref.refType(ref.types.void), [ 'int' ] ]
});

console.log(testlib.SampleAddInt(5, 9));
console.log(testlib.Addition(5));
```

В консоле получаю:

```
14
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Первая функция отрабатывает; вторая, соответственно, нет. Как правильно объявить тип `vector`, используя пакет `ffi`? Желательно не меняя кода самой библиотеки.
Либо подскажите любой другой вариант подключения билиотек.

Comment: Меня терзают смутные сомнения, что js в состоянии понять, что такое `vector<int>`... Откуда ему знать внутреннее устройство таких страшных вещей? С тем же успехом вы можете создать какой-то свой класс и удивляться, что он не работает с Node.js. "Попроще надо быть, попроще" (с)...

Comment: @Harry да, и поэтому на выход надо падавать какой-нить массив согласно спецификации типов переменных javascipt.

Comment: slippyk, согласно спецификации nodejs, для создания аддонов, нужно использовать обертки, которые предоставляют набор макросов для взаимодействия с V8 (`nan` например), либо напрямую использовать API V8, и как подметил @Harry V8 без понятия что такое `std::vector`, потому что API V8 предоставляет `v8::Array` из коробки

Comment: ffi работает только с С интерфейсами, для std::vector придется делать аддон оборачивающий эти фукции, в котором из вектора будет делаться `v8::Array`.